# Index with max number Power BI

Tags: indexing, powerbi, max, dax, powerquery

I need some help with indexing tables with a cap on the index number.

The goal is an index from lets say 1:15. When the index reaches 15, then it should do another iteration of 1:15 indexing until the end. The number is dependent on another index in another table with no relationship.

Any recommendations on how to proceed?

Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: need to see some sample data and your expected output from them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add your index, developed any way you like.  Then add a custom column that uses Number.Mod to convert the first column into repeating number groups.  The below counts sequentially from 0...X then converts that to repeating numbers of 1...15 in a second column. Delete the original index after

```
letSource = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Added Index" = Table.AddIndexColumn(Source, "Index", 0, 1),
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Index", "NewIndex", each 1+Number.Mod([Index],15))
in #"Added Custom"
```